# Ionic: Unable to run ionic serve with WARN:ionic project has been renamed to ionic.config.json

Tags: ionic-framework, bower

My folder for ionic is working in the working but without doing anything, it can not run with command ionic serve. It ask to change ionic.project or run npm bower install. I choose to install bower and it shown "WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.". rename it and run ionic serve but the app doesn't appear.

The method I rename the ionic.project is press F2 and change to "ionic.config.json"

```
D:\app_abc\abc\.git\cha>ionic service
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.

You must have bower installed to continue.
Type `npm install -g bower` (CLI v2.0.0-beta.25)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
OS:
Node Version: v5.11.1



D:\abc\abc\.git\cha>npm install -g bower
C:\Users\jane\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\jane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
C:\Users\jane\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- bower@1.8.0


D:\abc\abc\.git\cha>ionic service
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.

D:\abc\abc\.git\cha>ionic service

D:\abc\abc\.git\cha>ionic service
Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?
```

Comment: couldnt find ionic.config.json that means config file is not there.check spelling again and try ionic serve

Answer (score -2):

you are not in ionic project. So it is throwing error.

Example: your project name is ioninProject

Then, path should be like this

D:\abc\abc.git\cha\ionicProject>ionic service